# How can we improve SSL handshake to increase the security?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, server, cl

During SSL handshake, the server send the client its(server's) public key and then client creates a session key and encrypt it with the server's public key and send it to the server. The server then decrypt the message with its private key and retrive the session key. The further communication between server and client is then secured using symmetric key.

Now here, if the initial public key sent by server goes to malicious device then it will create its own session key and encrypt it with the public key and send it to the server. Then the whole communication will take place betwneen server and malicious device.
How can we fix it?

Comment: If the public key is not signed, then there is no way to fix it. That's where a certificate chain comes in. Certificate pinning is another option.

Comment: A better site to ask this kind of questions is security.stackexchange.com. But I recommend that you first learn more about how TLS works by reading http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work, especially the parts about certificates and authentication.

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct. The client does not encrypt or send the session key, It is negotiated via a key agreement protocol. Your question is based on a misapprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you quite have this right. The connection is supposed to be:

```
client <--> server
```

The client *knows* that it's talking to the server due to the SSL handshake and validation of the server certificate. Your question is what would happen if:

```
client  //   MiTM <--> server
```

with the client being out of the communication loop. In this situation the server's standard authentication and authorization will view the MiTM as an unauthorized client and provide it with no sensitive data.

Perhaps you're asking what happens if the initial connection is something like:

```
client <--> MiTM <--> server
```

where the MiTM is some malicious network appliance. At first the server talks to the client to get the user authenticated but then (unknowningly) begins speaking to the MiTM. This can't happen as the user won't authenticate until the SSL connection is set up. As SSL connections are designed to deal with malicious MiTM attacks successfully, the MiTM can see the traffic but can't understand it.

The key insight here is that the server won't trust a client until it gets an authentication over SSL and the client won't authenticate until it gets a secure SSL channel. Once the SSL channel is correctly established between the client and server, MiTMs are powerless to do anything besides block the connection.

In short, SSL works.

Comment: I am talking about the situation
 client  //   MiTM <--> server
In this situation to prevent server communication with MitM which authorization technique should we use?

Comment: Basic, digest, or SSL mutual auth are all fine because SSL protects you. The client won't send the credentials unless there's a secure connection with the server

Comment: I am workiing on IoT, in which 2 peer devices will be authenticating each other by sending each other a unique id and verifying the other's id with the server. Here to secure the transfer of the unique id, what can I do?

Comment: I guess I'm confused why you are concerned about sending it over SSL?

Comment: Neil, I am totally naive in this field. And I am assigned the work of authentication and encryption for peer to peer devices.
What will be the best approach in this work?

Comment: You're going to find a tutorial or something on designing secure web apps. I don't have one to point you to. Regarding this question, just assume that a properly created SSL connection ensures confidentiality, integrity, and authenticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Key_concepts).

Comment: Thanks neil smithline

Comment: The *client* won't trust the *server* until it has established an authentication via PKI. The server authenticates, not the client.